# Parameter Optimisation with system of ODEs

Tags: python, optimization, ode

I have a pair of ODEs which I am currently attempting to fit to a small dataset I have, however I am having some issues optimising two parameters (a and c). The ODEs take a slightly altered Lotka-Volterra form given by:

dT/dt = aT - bTL/(T+L+G)

dL/dt = cTL/(T+L+G) - dL

where b, G and d are known, and a small dataset is available for T(t) (but not L(t)).

Currently I have tried using odeint to solve the system of equations, and defined a residual function to be used in lmfit.Minimize, however my solutions don't quite fit the data regardless of the method chosen within lmfit.Minimize and any changes to the boundaries.

The current code is as follows:

```
def eqns(y, t, paras):
    T,L=y
    
    try:
        c = paras['c'].value
        a = paras['a'].value

    except KeyError:
        c, a = paras

    b = 60*24    
    G = 1.7E9    
    d = 0.068
    
    return [a*T-b*L*(T/(G+T+L)),c*T*(L/(G+T+L))-d*L]

# Solution to differential equations T'(t) = model(t,x,paras), given initial condition T0
def sol(t, x0, paras):
    return odeint(eqns, x0, t, args=(paras,),rtol=1e-8,hmin=0.001,hmax=0.1)


# Define function to compute residuals
def residual(paras, t, data):
    arg0 = paras['T0'].value, paras['L0'].value
    model = sol(t, arg0, paras)
    x2_model = model[:, 0]
    return ((x2_model - data)**2).ravel()


# Set initial conditions
T0 = 50000
L0 = 1
y0 = [T0, L0]

# Measured data
t_measured = np.array([18,21,26,28,33])
T_measured = np.array([12667366.43,24917043.97,74910183.58,122959334.2,157298406])

# Set parameters including bounds
params = Parameters()
params.add('T0', value=T0, vary=False)
params.add('L0', value=L0, vary=False)
params.add('c', value=3, min=0.1, max=100)
params.add('a', value=0.2, min=0.01, max=10)

# Fit model
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t_measured, T_measured), method='leastsq')

# Check effectiveness of fit
data_fitted = sol(np.linspace(0., 100, 1000), y0, result.params)

# Statistics of Fit
report_fit(result)
```

I'm fairly certain the limits on a and c are reasonable given the system, however the fit still doesn't work. Is there something wrong in the residual function?

Comment: You state "I'm fairly certain the limits on a and c are reasonable given the system, however the fit still doesn't work. I"  what is the basis for your concern?  What problem needs resolution besides help me fix this thing?

Comment: Sorry the question wasn't quite clear. The limits on a and c are reasonable so don't need changing, but the solution, when plotted, doesn't conform to the measured data and produces huge error bars (from report_fit). So the question is, could this be due to the residual function? Or the integration?

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- the `odeint` integrator and any other numerical integrator applies the initial condition `x0` to the first number given in the time span or time array. Here that is `t=18`, which from context is wrong, as apparently the simulation should start at `t=0`. There are two solutions to this,

  - prepend `0` to the time array, `t=np.insert(t,0,0.0)` and remove this value from the result, `return odeint(...)[1:]`. This can give problems in when for the plot the time array actually starts at `0`.
  - switch to `solve_ivp` where time span and evaluation times are different parameters.

    ```
    def sol(t, x0, paras):
        res = solve_ivp(eqns, (0,max(t)+10), x0, t_eval=t, args=(paras,),\
                        atol=[1e-2,1e-4],rtol=1e-9)
        return res.y
    ```

    Note that the result is transpose to the `odeint` one, so you need next `x2_model = model[0]`
- The residuals were unnecessarily squared. This might throw off the algorithm inside `lmfit.minimize`, so use just `return (x2_model - data).ravel()`
- As one may note, I have set the `atol` parameter. Deviating from the currently set range, either as single value or as value-per-component tuple, gives rather large increases in the error estimate.

Then the parameters get estimated as

```
    c:   19.7725209 +/- 0.62555507 (3.16%) (init = 3)
    a:   0.27960923 +/- 0.00146551 (0.52%) (init = 0.2)
```

which appears to be quite good, the plot also looks like a good fit

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I've managed to get similar values to those you shared. One issue is the data I'm working with should have all points in the initial slope (i.e. before the peak), would this be an issue with the atol parameter?

Comment: No, I do not think so. I would suspect that you would need to adapt the other parameters. Or a longer time series of measured data. What sometimes helps is to normalize the variables in the model, so that the solver sees components that mostly have sizes 0.1 to 100, or similarly centered around 1. It is possible that the solvers, especially the "meta" solver `minimize`, are not exhaustively tested on how their heuristic parts react to wildly different scales in the state components and residuals.